# Error on pip install boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto, boto3

I'm trying to run:

```
pip install boto3
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
DEPRECATION: Uninstalling a distutils installed project (six) has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. This is due to the fact that uninstalling a distutils project will only partially uninstall the project.
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-ueLGpf-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
```

Comment: Maybe a permission problem. Try `sudo pip install boto3`

Comment: This issue is described [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3165). Try: `pip install --ignore-installed six`

Comment: In python, always setup a virtual development environment , e.g. virtualenv or conda : http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
pip install --ignore-installed boto3
```